# NSURLRequest/URLWithString not loading entire web page text

Tags: html, ios, xpath

I'm starting an iOS project that includes parsing some data out of web pages. I was planning to use

I started using "http://www.facebook.com." as my test case, and XPath (using Libxml2 via Hpple ) to parse the pages. XPath/Hpple seems to work well, but I noticed that I couldn't find user's posts from the page. After trying many combinations of XPath commands, I realized the user posts aren't in the text NSURLRequest or URLWithString give me at all. From what I can tell it seems like lots of structure type data.

When I use FireFox & FireBug I see the posts, in Div nodes such as

```
<div data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;}" class="mbs _5pbx userContent">We are accepting donations at our thrift store!! Please bring your gently used items here/div>
```

And when I get the page source directly from FireFox, most user posts are missing from it too. So one of the following things are happening.

1. I don't understand the structure of HTML and need to use a different way to load this text.
2. FB has a very complicated HTML that is encoding/hiding the text in some manner.
3. There are some settings with NSURL I don't understand that are encoding/not loading this text in some way I can't find it.

I could start with a simpler web site but I chose FB because of it's complexity, as I want to make sure the parser I write will work on any site it's given.

I'm sure this is a pretty obvious misunderstanding on my part on how to parse web pages, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could start with a simpler web site but I chose FB because of it's complexity, as I want to make sure the parser I write will work on any site it's given.

Probably not the best way to start. Better get some experiences with simpler problems before hitting the complex cases.

---

Regarding your specific question: **Don't try to scrape Facebook.** They use lots of ajax to fetch data, do first step would be to use a headless browser which you need to automate (but that will lead to a heavy drop in performance). Next, they often change their website, and parsing it is likely to break often.

On the other hand, they offer a [**stable and easy-to-use API**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), which is [also available as SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph/).

Comment: We want to handle multiple sites so I probably can't use the FB API, but I marked this as an answer and upvoted because it's clearly the best solution if doing something exclusively with the FB site itself, I looked at the API briefly and it's pretty impressive, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge difference between single HTML page, which is basically single text file, and a page shown 'in action' in browser, which acts like a compiler over HTML source, loads JS, CSS, Image and other files, starts executing JavaScripts (and other scripts), which in turn might load a lot of JSON data, which in turn mught load a lot of additional HTML or dynamically change DOM model.

`NSURLRequest`/`URLWithString` returns you just original HTML - small text file.

What you see in Firefox as a user, or examining DOM model via FireBug - this is what browsers are made for, and this thing is different from the file you receive with 
`NSURLRequest`/`URLWithString` metods.

So, if you understand all these complexity, either you want to develop your own browser, or you need to look at WebKit and see if it might help you.

Comment: Yea, this makes perfect sense, I should have realized this but obviously needed you to explain it for me. Looks like my client is going to want me using WebKit.